# Ajax.BeginForm + ModelState.AddModelError + ValidationSummary: not able to display error. Why?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I follow different post here on SO about this topic, but I'm really not able to figure it out how to show validation error in `MVC`, using `Ajax`. 
I do (using an `Ajax.BeginForm`):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "body",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementId = "loadingOverlay",
        OnComplete = "AjaxBeginFormOnComplete",
        OnSuccess = "AjaxBeginFormOnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "AjaxBeginFormOnFailure"
    }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ErrorNotLogged);

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 mx-auto">
            <div class="card">
                // input data and such
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

On the Controller, I add the `ModelState.AddModelError`:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorNotLogged", "Error Message");

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Here's the ViewMmodel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Customs))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Customs), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredEmail")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Customs), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Customs))]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Customs), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredPassword")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "KeepMeLoggedIn", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Customs))]
    public bool KeepMeLoggedIn { get; set; }

    public string ErrorNotLogged { get; set; }
}
```

So, I need to display (after an AJAX request) a (list of) error/s, generated with AddModelError.

It does the correct Ajax call. But when response complete, I can't see any error returned, any html, nothing! Where am I wrong?

Tried different aspects, but nothing works:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)

ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error Message");
return PartialView("Login", model);

[Required]
public string ErrorNotLogged { get; set; }
```

Should I call some JS function client-side? I still can't see the html returned with the "error" span and message, anyway...

Answer (score -1):

You should put your properties in razor. Try using **@Html.EditorFor** or **@Html.TextBoxFor**, for example:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ErrorNotLogged);

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try the which one:

1. remove de AjaxOptions (OnComplete, OnSuccess, OnFailure). **OR**
2. after AjaxOptions give a ID to the form (`..., new AjaxOptions { }, new { @id = "MyID"`) on browser console run: 
   `$('#MyID').valid(); $('#MyID').validate().errorList` (will return the
   errors - just to check if validation works fine). **OR**

For more info look @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: Of course I have those properties. My problem is validation after a Server model state, not client. That works well before submitting data.

Comment: Well... so you should explain/expose your problem better... Your question and now your comment turns it "inconsistent".

Comment: I've exposed what's my problem: I need to display (after an ajax request) a (list of) error/s, generated with AddModelError. can you help me? Edit the question and I'll upvote

Comment: Check my answer edited, anyway when you declare AjaxOptions you must have that JS functions with parameters (xhr, status, data).

Comment: Of course I have that function! They do nothing right now, shouldn't?